# RegEx replacement in NotePad++

Tags: regex

I need to replace many different lines in a html file where lines look like this:

```
<span lang="en-ca">random string</span>
```

with just

```
random string
```

For example

```
my<span lang="en-ca"> dog</span> likes<span lang="en-ca"> ice cream</span>.
```

would be updated to be

```
my dog likes ice cream.
```

I've found I can use

```
<span lang="en-ca">.*</span>
```

to match the general pattern in the find parameter, but not what to use in the replace parameter.

If this can this be done, how so?

Note: I can't simply replace all the

```
<span lang="en-ca">
```

and

`</span>`

separately, as not every

`</span>`

is paired with a

`<span lang="en-ca">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following search string :

```
<span lang="en-ca">(.*?)</span>
```

Replace by `\1`.

The `?` means a non-greedy search (otherwise it can match multiple
occurrences in one go). The parenthesis create a group, and `\1` uses
the contents of this group.

Ensure that Search mode is set to
"Regular expression".
If a group can cross line boundaries,
check `. matches newline`.

Comment: Perfect - thank you